# there was a network error (file:///android_asset/www/skinloader.html)

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a project using IBM Worklight 6.2. The application is running fine in browser. I added the android environment and generated the android apk file.

When I install the apk in my mobile device and try open the application i am getting this error:

> network error (file:///android_asset/www/skinloader.html)

I have checked all the other questions with same errors. But nothing has an working solution. Can someone provide an idea as how this could be rectified.
below is my log cat message when I try to run the application in the emulator.

```
06-17 18:25:42.139: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(1957): Ignore this event
06-17 18:25:54.504: D/CordovaWebViewClient(1957): onPageStarted(file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
06-17 18:25:54.504: D/CordovaActivity(1957): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
06-17 18:25:54.508: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(1957): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html
06-17 18:25:54.639: D/CordovaWebViewClient(1957): CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-1 Description=net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND URL=file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html
06-17 18:25:54.639: D/CordovaActivity(1957): onMessage(onReceivedError,{"errorCode":-1,"description":"net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND","url":"file:\/\/\/android_asset\/www\/skinLoader.html"})
06-17 18:25:54.655: D/CordovaWebViewClient(1957): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
06-17 18:25:54.655: D/CordovaActivity(1957): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
06-17 18:25:54.661: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(1957): Ignore this event
06-17 18:25:55.043: I/Choreographer(1957): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-17 18:25:56.152: D/CordovaLog(1957): data:text/html,chromewebdata: Line 12 : Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png
06-17 18:25:56.167: I/chromium(1957): [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (12)
```

[image: The below is the screenshort of what I see in mobile when I try to open the application]

Comment: Provide your worklight project - upload it to dropbox

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3tjt4ao7fxulzr8/AAAAvmbJJ1JoRyAK0qRKW9U2a?dl=0 this the link to the dropbox where my project is hosted

Comment: I have added the certificate and it is working fine in the browser. Also if I use mobile first  7.0 and generate the apk it is working fine. Only with Mobile first 6.2 I facing this problem.

Comment: You did not understand my criticism. whatever... doesn't matter.

Comment: What is the solution? I have faced the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the application rom the provided .zip file and running it in Worklight 6.2 worked successfully, I saw the login screen.

You will need to edit your question and provide LogCat logs.

Comment: My problem is only when I generate the apk file for android .It is working fine when I run it on the browser.

Comment: I have just added the screenshot of the error which I get . Also I tried to traverse through the .apk file (changing the extenstion to zip) and I am not able to find the skinloader.html file in the www folder

Comment: please find the log cat added

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with MobileFirst Studio 7.0.0. Make sure that you are using Oracle JDK setting JAVA_HOME plus PATH environment variables.